# Why modifications from Iterator aren't visible during iteration?

Tags: java, iterator, addition

After some time learning **Java**, I decided to revise `listIterator` methods. So I made following simple code:

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add("red");
colors.add("blue");
colors.add("green");

ListIterator<String> iterator = colors.listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
    String color = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(color);

    if (color.equals("blue")){
        iterator.add("yellow");
    }
}
```

What I was expecting was that **iterator** adds `'yellow'` right after `'blue'`. But when I run it, I got surprised. Result is :

```
red-blue-green
```

And not as I expected:

```
red-blue-yellow-green
```

What is the point of **iterator's** `add()` method when it is not updating **collecting** during **iteration**? And yes, if I were to call `System.out.println(colors)`, it would show me all 4 colors. But why not simply add `'yellow'` so **Iterator** can 'see' it?

Comment: As per the java docs for `add` method of `ListIterator`, the add will increase by 1 the value to returned by a call to nextIndex or previousIndex, so you added, cursor moved to this item and on `next()`, cursor returned the element after your added element. In order to see, you will have to call `.previous()` and then `next()`

Comment: @SSC that comment sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @SSC Can you make an answer and elaborate a little bit mate? I am not quite sure I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is like that because that is how it is specified:

[JavaDocs for ListIterator.add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)):

> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element.

I suppose the rationale behind this decision is something like this:
If you just added an element, you are usually not interested to immediately processing it on the next call to `next()`. Instead, most frequently you just want to add elements to the collection based on the elements that it contained before starting the iteration. You already know the element you just added, so you can just do any processing it needs directly.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [java docs for add method of ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)), the add will increase by 1 the value to returned by a call to `nextIndex` or `previousIndex`, so when you added, cursor moved to this item and on `next()`, cursor returned the element after your added element. In order to see, you will have to call `.previous()` and then `next()`.